# Zepplin: Spark with user defined python version

Tags: python, apache-spark, configure, apache-zeppelin

The default python version of our Spark cluster is 2.7. Howerver, lots of spark projects are based on python3.7. When I use spark-submit, I can use these params to solve the problem:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.yarn.dist.archives=/my/python/path.tar.gz --conf spark.pyspark.driver.python=/my/python/path/python --conf spark.pyspark.python=/my/python/path/python
```

However, when adding the params to "zeppelin-env.sh"

```
export SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--conf spark.yarn.dist.archives=/my/python/path.tar.gz --conf spark.pyspark.driver.python=/my/python/path/python --conf spark.pyspark.python=/my/python/path/python"
```

It does not work.
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: have you tried to set these `--conf` options on the Spark interpreter level? everything that starts with `spark.` will be passed to the `spark-submit`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works as follow:
step1: configure
%spark.conf
spark.yarn.dist.archives=file:/usr/local/python-3.6.9/python-3.6.9.tar.gz#python-3.6.9
spark.pyspark.driver.python=/usr/local/python-3.6.9/bin/python3.6
spark.pyspark.python=./python-3.6.9/bin/python3.6

step2: restart
restart this interpret to make the configuration takes effect

step3: run the code
# this is in python-3.6.9.tar.gz
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

Comment: I meant - can you try to specify these parameters in the interpreter config, not on the notebook level?

Comment: I tried to adjust the parameters in interpreter setting, but it did not work. The adjusted parameters are PYSPARK_PYTHON,PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON